# Change a view in a table view cell following a button press in another view

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I want to change the background color of a view I have in a table view cell following a button press in another view in the table view. the view is connected as an IBOutlet to a table view cell class. Iv'e tried using delegation but it didn't seem to work:

```
//tableview class
protocol ViewDelegate {
    func changeBackground()
}
...
var delegate: ViewDelegate?

//the IBAction {
    delegate?.changeBackground()   
}

//tableviewcell class
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell , ViewDelegate {
    func changeBackground() {
        self.cellView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

how do I do it? many thanks :)

Comment: Can you ask your question in simple words ... Maybe I can help you but I didn't understand you question.

Comment: Where are you setting the delegate? Could you put the piece of code in which you set the delegate to that view?.

Comment: @ХристоАтанасов Bascially I need to change a view, that is in a table view cell, after a button in another view was pressed.

Comment: @BarbaraRodeker In the UITableView class I declare the protocol, with the function to change the background, and in the UITableViewCell class I implement the function, cellView is the view that I want to change it's background color. then in the button's IBAction I call the function, but it doesn't appear to be working

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on this line: self.cellView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()? to make sure it's reached and cellView is not nil?

Comment: @BarbaraRodeker what do you mean? cellView is a property of the TableViewCell class...

Comment: you just need an @IBAction in tableViewController, connected to the button, and in it cellView.backgroundcolor = UIColor.redColor()

Comment: @ХристоАтанасов yes, but the cellView is not in the same class as the button

Comment: Try grabbing the current instance of that class (on buttonTapped event)  and change the color ...